# Several type of authentification google assistant

Tags: node.js, dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I am currently testing to implement account linking by voice.
This system works perfectly but I would like to leave the option to the user to give him the possibility to connect via a classic oauth web page. Is this possible? If yes, how to do it ?

I would really appreciate a link or a helper because I can't find anything :(

Thanks to you the community :)

Comment: I think you are integrating Dialogflow, Assistant and AoG, if not, please share the documentation to understand your configuration. But if so, in `Google Actions Console -> Develop -> Account linking` in the `Linking type` step there are [two options](https://developers.google.com/assistant/identity/oauth2): `Google Sign In` and `OAuth & Google Sign In`. Can you let us know if this OAuth option is the one you are searching for? Once selected you can opt by Implicit or Authorization code. If it is not helpful, please clarify, with an image if possible what is the "classic oauth web page".

Comment: We already have an oral connection that works on our application. We have put the google sign in & oauth option. However, we want to give the user the possibility to choose the method: oral or through a web page. 
Currently, despite the fact that we have put the google sign in & oauth option, it is only possible to connect by voice. 
How to allow the user to connect in the other way?
 I don't know if this is clearer?

Thank you !! :)

Comment: You already have an oral authentication and Account Linking documentation mentions that an UI can be displayed with [consent screen](https://developers.google.com/identity/account-linking/oauth-linking?oauth=implicit#design_guidelines), this seems the classic UI you referred, but the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/assistant/identity/oauth-concept-guide#how_it_works) is not clear if integration is possible; _..Google opens your authorization endpoint in the user’s browser. If the flow started on a voice-only device for an Action, Google would transfer the execution to a phone_.

Comment: I'm not an expert in Google Assistant and OAuth, but I found some steps in [Designing the voice user interface for the authentication flow](https://developers.google.com/assistant/identity/google-sign-in#design_the_voice_user_interface_for_the_authentication_flow) that maybe you can review and can help to incorporate both options somehow by programming.